# Broken links in hg serve behind nginx via proxy_pass

Tags: mercurial, nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I have a simple Ubuntu 10.10, Nginx, Mercurial, PHP, and MySQL stack.

Current file structure:

```
/opt/nginx/html - document root for nginx (where my website files are)
/opt/nginx/html/.hg - repository data
/usr/share/mercurial/ - where the templates/static folder is
```

I am running hg -serve which is hosted at localhost:8000. 
I do not have a clear understanding of how mercurial is linked to its resources after this point.

I have the following Nginx configuration for my desired entry point:

```
location /mercurial/ {
    auth_basic    "Authentication";
    auth_basic_user_file    /opt/nginx/html/.hg/file.password;
    proxy_pass    http://localhost:8000/;
}
```

This works fine except for fully loading the Mercurial Instance after authenticating. I get the page i expect to see but the /static references are all broken, and the links I click on such as one of the changesets is broken as well (they are not found or take me back to the broken main page). It tries to find these files at my-ip-address/static/... which is incorrect.

The mercurial ui directory is outside of my document root /opt/nginx/html. 
The path of where /static actually is: /usr/share/mercurial/templates
Is this the problem?? That the files are outside of my nginx document root?
When mercurial runs where is /rev and how can i make sure that mercurial runs correctly with the correct resource URLs?

**Note**: Just going to my-ip-address:8000 works 100%. Nothing is broken and no css or js is missing. The problem is happening with regards to the proxy_pass.

How can I have these files properly linked up? Is a rewrite required?

Comment: The question is why is it broken? It hg serve sending you to a wrong address? What would be the link you want to go to.

Comment: if I go to my-ip-address:8000 everything works perfectly, however, I am making it so that is only accessable via proxy_pass if someone goes to my-ip-address/mercurial. this proxy_pass is causing some of the paths to be broken. i fixed the static redirect but rev is still not working. any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soultion: I needed to add the following to my NGINX config file;

```
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: `$proxy_add_x_forwared_for` should be `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for` of sure.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that by default, the web server launched with `hg serve` doesn't add any prefix to the URLs it generates. It has no way to know that you're NGinx proxy pass request for the /mercurial location.

You must set the prefix to use with the `--prefix` option. `hg help serve` tells us this about the option :

> --prefix PREFIX      prefix path to serve from (default: server root)

So just run the server this way : `hg serve --prefix mercurial` and everything should be fine ! (don't forget to remove your alias...)

If you prefer, the prefix option can also be set in the configuration file if you have one :

```
[web]
prefix = mercurial
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I gave this a try but the links are broken again and every link no matter the URI after .../mercurial/... loads the same broken first page. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by broken ? What's happening exactly and what are the link created ? (I think the best is to update the question instead of trying to explain it in the comments)